# Creating a folder and writing txt files to it to create a registration method (Java)

Tags: java-io

The folder being created in the root is the way I want it to be so that's fine. The method also creates the file and folder just fine but I don't know how to get it to be created in the folder.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public void registration(TextField user, PasswordField pass){

    File admin = new File("adminstrator");

    if(!admin.exists()){
    admin.mkdir();
    }

   //add some way to save file to admin folder

    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("USER_PASS.txt", true))){

        bw.write(user.getText());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(pass.getText());
        bw.newLine();

        bw.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put admin as path before file name like that

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(admin + "\\USER_PASS.txt", true))){

    bw.write(user.getText());
    bw.newLine();
    bw.write(pass.getText());
    bw.newLine();
    bw.close();
}
catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think it is better to avoid using AWT components like TextField in your program. Use light weight Swing components instead, like JTextField and JPasswordField.
2. By using **File.separator** instead of a backslash you assure that your program will also behave correctly if you ever port it to another operating environment.
3. JPasswordField has a .getPassword() method which returns a character array. You can use it directly in your [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) write method. You can even convert it to a String ps = new String(pass.getPassword());.
4. It is always better to close your file in a finally block, because if an IOException occurs, it will skip the bw.close() method call, and your file will be left open.
5. e.printStackTrace() is a quick and dirty solution. Avoid using it because it writes to stderr and the output might get lost. Read [God's Perfect Exception](http://thinkinghard.com/blog/GodsPerfectException.html) in order to find out how God did it during Genesis. Use a logging framework. [slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org/) is a good option.

   ```
   public void registration(JTextField user, JPasswordField pass) {  // 1
      File admin = new File("adminstrator");
      BufferedWriter bw = null;
      if (!admin.exists()) {
         admin.mkdir();
      }

      try {
          bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(admin + File.separator + "USER_PASS.txt", true)); // 2
          bw.write(user.getText());
          bw.newLine();
          bw.write(pass.getPassword()); // 3          
          bw.newLine();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();  // 5
      } finally { // 4
          try {
             if (bw != null) {
                 bw.close();
             }
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace(); // 5
          }
      }
   }
   ```